# Fargate-unable to load aws credentials from any provider

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have zeppelin docker, I am trying to run on ECS with fargate. For the Zeppelin notebook, I want to configure s3 to store the notebook.

so I have created a bucket and added the permission to read/write the bucket for IAM role(The same is used in ECS task and Execution role)  .

When I start ECS+EC2 I see my application comes up, but when I select the launch type as fargate, my zeppelin application throws below error

```
Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

Is there any extra configuration required for fargate?